# Best practices for enterprise purchasing flows?

Tags: workflow, checkout, best-practice

I'm helping a team member redesign the purchasing flow for one of our main products

Right now (for a new user) the typical flow is: 1) land on pricing page --> 2) click "Buy now" --> 3) signup or signin --> 4) configure your purchase --> 5) enter billing details --> 6) review purchase --> 7) confirm purchase

my coworker and I can't think of anything to change regarding steps 1-3. the user needs an account to complete the purchase and access our product. but is it better to have the last few steps on their own screens, or combined into one? what other details are we not thinking of?

Comment: Step 3 should go away if the user is already signed in.

Comment: I would agree that step 4, 5, 6, and 7 should all be different pages. That is the standard model. Is there a reason you would want to deviate from that? Are you trying to limit the amount of pages shown?

Comment: They ABSOLUTELY need an account? Is this a service/SaaS type deal? If it's possible to add "Continue as Guest," that would be HUGE. If it's not, then your flow looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I would put steps 4-6 on the same page and then have 7 as an after the event acknowledgement that it worked along with an email or text.

The reason I don't like 6 pages is because at each page you can lose them. Their internet is slow, they disconnect, they get distracted and your transaction is gone.

Look at how [Amazon hit it out of the park thanks to one click ordering which I think they also have a patent on.](http://www.ecommercetimes.com/story/74719.html)

The fewer steps you have, the fewer areas you have to possibly lose their focus, attention, or internet connection before the transaction is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Actually (I know this question is rather old but I came across it looking for an answer of my own)- it would be wise to remove "sign up or sign in" (ie login or register) unless it is absolutley necessary, as users may abandon when they are forced to sign in. Read about the 300 million dollar button! https://www.fastcompany.com/1147825/300-million-continue-button